# What is Gactions SIGN_IN intent JSON response format

Tags: actions-on-google

Would someone please give me an example of the JSON Google expects when returning a actions.intent.SIGN_IN intent? I'm trying to get my app approved and I believe the JSON I'm returning is invalid. Google support is only telling me that my app is unhealthy and not responding correctly. Below is the JSON I'm returning on a fulfillment request to my server:

```
{
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "expectedInputs": [{
            "inputPrompt": {
                "initialPrompts": [{
                        "textToSpeech": "You must link your Google Assistant."
                    }
                ],
                "noInputPrompts": []
            },
            "possibleIntents": [{
                    "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON format is documented:

```
{
  "conversationToken": "{\"state\":null,\"data\":{}}",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [
    {
      "inputPrompt": {
        "initialPrompts": [
          {
            "textToSpeech": "PLACEHOLDER_FOR_SIGN_IN"
          }
        ],
        "noInputPrompts": []
      },
      "possibleIntents": [
        {
          "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
          "inputValueData": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/account-linking#json

Comment: Thank you, I did have a change to make.

Comment: Will the JSON I have in my original post get processed successfully, since it is missing a couple of fields? It's missing "conversationToken" and "inputValueData".

Answer (score 1):

Leons link above does not seem to lead to the answer any longer (maybe V1?). In fact, unless you're using the Google NodeJS SDK, the answer is very difficult to find. This link:

https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json

Provides some info - look for actions.intent.SIGN_IN. The SignInValueSpec data spec is here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/SignInValueSpec

You end up with a response like this:

```
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Please sign in"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "systemIntent": {
        "intent": "actions.intent.SIGN_IN",
        "data": {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.SignInValueSpec",
          "optContext": "To verify your age"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh - the Dialogflow webhook response has a different format spec to the direct conversation webhook response.